# Changing default page with login page in yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii framework. Can anyone tell me how to change default page?
I want first login page as a default page.
please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

> protected/config/main.php

```
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'My application',
    'defaultController' => 'myController/myAction',   // <--- add this line and replace with correct controller/action
```

further more detail refer this [LINKS](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24895-want-to-change-default-url-from-siteindex-to-mycontrollermyaction/) (Read jodev answer)

Comment: 'defaultController' => 'site/login',

Comment: i have done it but its giving me "Setting unknown property: yii\web\Application::defaultController" error.any solution fr it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the config file, change the 'defaultController' to whatever default controller you use to load the login page.